# Cannot ready property of undefined

Tags: angular, angular6

After selecting an application from the drop-down list, the user has the option of either selecting a navigation from the drop-down list or adding a new navigation.

If the user selects a navigation from the drop-down list, the respective details of the navigation should be populated in the form.  And if the user clicks on the Add New Menu button, the same form should populate with all the fields empty.

The error that comes up when the user clicks on the Add New Menu button is "Cannot read property 'NavName' of undefined".  I tried initializing the Navigation item in the OnInit method, but that didn't help.

Here is the code:

application.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="applications">
    <mat-option (click)="sendChangedId(app.Id)"  *ngFor="let app of apps" [value]="app.Id">
      {{app.ApplicationName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

application.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationService } from '../application.service';
import { IApplication } from '../IApplication';
import { ShareAppIDService } from '../share-app-id.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-application',
  templateUrl: './application.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./application.component.css']
})
export class ApplicationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  apps: Array<IApplication>;

  constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService, private shareAppIdService: ShareAppIDService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.applicationService
      .getApplications()
      .subscribe(data => {this.apps = data; } );
  }

  sendChangedId(appId) {
    this.shareAppIdService.changeAppId(appId);
    console.log('app id from app controller is ' + appId);
  }
}
```

share-app-id.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareAppIDService {

  constructor() { }

  private appId = new Subject();
  public appIdChanged = this.appId.asObservable();

  public changeAppId(value) {
    this.appId.next(value);
    console.log('app id from changeAppId service is ' + value);
  }
}
```

navigation.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="navigations" >
  <mat-option (click)="sendChangedNav(nav)" *ngFor="let nav of navigations" [value]="nav.Id">
    {{nav.NavName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br/>
<div *ngIf="appId > 0">
<button (click)="sendChangedNavDetail(appId)">Add New Menu Item</button>
</div>
<app-navigation-detail></app-navigation-detail>
```

navigation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../navigation.service';
import { INavigation } from '../INavigation';
import { ShareAppIDService } from '../share-app-id.service';
import { ShareNavigationService } from '../share-navigation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  navigations: Array<INavigation>;
  appId: number;

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService, private shareAppIdService: ShareAppIDService,
    private sharedNavService: ShareNavigationService) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.shareAppIdService.appIdChanged.subscribe((appId: number) => {
      this.appId = appId;
      this.navigationService
        .getNavigations(appId)
        .subscribe(data => {this.navigations = data; });
        console.log(this.appId);
    });
  }

  sendChangedNav(nav) {
    this.sharedNavService.changeNavigation(nav);
  }

  sendChangedNavDetail(appId) {
    this.sharedNavService.updateNavigationDetail(true);
    this.shareAppIdService.changeAppId(appId);
  }
}
```

share-navigation.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { INavigation } from './INavigation';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareNavigationService {

  constructor() { }

  private navigation = new Subject<INavigation>();
  public navigationChanged = this.navigation.asObservable();

  private showNavigationDetail = new Subject<boolean>();
  public navigationDetailChanged = this.showNavigationDetail.asObservable();

  public changeNavigation(value) {
    this.navigation.next(value);
    console.log('navigation from changeNavigation service is ' + value);
  }

  public updateNavigationDetail(value) {
    this.showNavigationDetail.next(value);
  }
}
```

navigation-detail.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="navigation != null || showNavDetail">
<form>
  <label for="navName">Navigation Name</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="navName" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavName" >
  <br/>
  <label for="navId">Nav ID</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="navId" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavId" >
  <br/>
  <label for="navParentCode">Nav Parent Code</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="navParentCode" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavParentId">
  <br/>
  <label for="navPageURL">Page URL</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="navPageURL" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavPageURL">
  <br/>
  <label for="navPosition">Position</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="navPosition" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavPosition">
  <br/>
  <label for="navRoleAccess">Role Access</label>
  <br/>
  <input id="textboxid" type="text" name="navRoleAccess" [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavRoleId">
  <br/>
  <label for="navTargetPage">Target Page</label>
  <br/>
  <select [(ngModel)]="navigation.NavTarget">
    <option>_target</option>
    <option>_blank</option>
    <option>_parent</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" [id]="navigation.NavActive" [name]="navigation.NavActive"
    [checked]="navigation.NavActive === 'Y' ? true:false"
    (change)="onActiveChange(navigation, $event)">Navigation Active
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" [id]="navigation.NavDesktop" [name]="navigation.NavDesktop"
    [checked]="navigation.NavDesktop === 'Y' ? true:false"
    (change)="onDesktopChange(navigation, $event)">Desktop View
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" [id]="navigation.NavTablet" [name]="navigation.NavTablet"
    [checked]="navigation.NavTablet === 'Y' ? true:false"
    (change)="onTabletChange(navigation, $event)">Tablet View
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" [id]="navigation.NavPhone" [name]="navigation.NavPhone"
    [checked]="navigation.NavPhone === 'Y' ? true:false"
    (change)="onPhoneChange(navigation, $event)">Phone View
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(navigation)">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
```

navigation-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ValueTransformer } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import { INavigation } from '../INavigation';
import { ShareNavigationService } from '../share-navigation.service';
import { ShareAppIDService } from '../share-app-id.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation-detail',
  templateUrl: './navigation-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-detail.component.css']
})
export class NavigationDetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  navigation: INavigation;
  showNavDetail: boolean;

  constructor(private sharedNavService: ShareNavigationService,
      private sharedAppService: ShareAppIDService
    ) {
      // this.navigation.NavName = '';
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.navigation.NavName = '';
    }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.sharedNavService.navigationChanged.subscribe((navigation) => {
      if (navigation != null) {
      this.navigation = navigation;
      console.log('navigation detail id is: ' + navigation.NavPageURL);
      navigation.NavTarget = navigation.NavTarget;
      console.log('navActive' + navigation.NavActive);
      }
    });


    this.sharedAppService.appIdChanged.subscribe((appId: number) => {
      console.log('appId in nav detail is' + appId);
      // this.navigation.NavAppId = appId;
    });

    this.sharedNavService.navigationDetailChanged.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('show nav detail is' + data);
      this.showNavDetail = data;
    });
  }

  onActiveChange(navigation, event) {
    this.navigation.NavActive = event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
  }

  onDesktopChange(navigation, event) {
    this.navigation.NavDesktop = event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
  }

  onTabletChange(navigation, event) {
    this.navigation.NavTablet = event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
  }

  onPhoneChange(navigation, event) {
    this.navigation.NavPhone = event.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
  }

  onSubmit(navigation) {
    alert('Submitting data:' + JSON.stringify(navigation));
  }

}
```

Comment: you are initilaizing `this.navigation.NavName = ''` how does that make sense if `navigation` itself is `undefined`?

Comment: Also, `navigationChanged` is getting a boolean on `Subscription`, this means you would be trying to access something like: `true.navName` later after the subscription, this would not give an error but always give you an `undefined` value

Comment: to your first point, how do I initialize Navigation when the user clicks on "Add New Menu Item"?

Comment: navigationDetailChanged is getting a boolean.

Comment: Hmm, ideally you should have a Naviagtion model, like a `class` which holds all the Navigation properties. But for now, you can just do `this.naviagtion = {}` in your `ngOnOnit()` of NabigationDetailsComponent

Comment: I get the error: Type {} is not assignable to type 'INavigation'.  Property 'Id' is missing in type '{}'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182977/discussion-between-ashish-ranjan-and-rds80).